# Grafana OAuth2 by Google and HTTPS

Tags: google-oauth, grafana

Trying to set up OAUTH 2 for access to Grafana (https by openssl)

Grafana v8.0.5 is hosted on AWS EC2 accessed via subdomain. Been working fine for months but time came to improve security, hence https & OAuth.

I followed [this link](https://www.turbogeek.co.uk/grafana-how-to-configure-ssl-https-in-grafana/) and configured https access & SSL. Worked like a charm!

I followed this link to configure Google OAuth [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/google/)
Below is the server options in grafana.ini

```
[server]
#Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
protocol = https

#The ip address to bind to, empty will bind to all interfaces
;http_addr =

#The http port  to use
http_port = 3000
#;http_port = 80

#The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = grafana.redacted.io

#Redirect to correct domain if host header does not match domain
#Prevents DNS rebinding attacks
;enforce_domain = false

#The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
#If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = https://grafana.redacted.io/login/google/

#Serve Grafana from subpath specified in `root_url` setting. By default it is set to 
`false` for compatibility reasons.
;serve_from_sub_path = false
```

Google.Auth options in grafana.ini are:

```
[auth.google]
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = false
client_id = theClientIdFromGoogleCloudConsole
client_secret = theClientSecretFromGoogleCloudConsole
scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
auth_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
token_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
api_url = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
allowed_domains = redacted.io
```

Google Console Settings
Authorised JS Origins: https://grafana.redacted.io:3000
Authorised redirect URIs: https://grafana.redacted.io/login/google

grafana service restarted and instance restarted.

Visiting URL:

1. https://grafana.redacted.io:3000 forwards to https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/login/google/login - page won't load
2. https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/login loads a page with text telling me "If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_from_sub_path to true."

Try:

```
serve_from_sub_path = true
```

Then revisit URL 2, the login page will load with the Google Auth button. Clicking it, loads "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch". This is obviously not what correct and reacding the specs I know I need this to be false

```
redirect_uri: https://grafana.redacted.io/login/google/login/google
```

Try:

```
root_url = https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/login/google
serve_from_sub_path = false
```

Update Google Console Redirect URL to equal root_url. Revisit URL 2 (above) and login screen loads again; click Google, safari error:

```
 Too many redirects occurred trying to open "https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/login/google/login"
```

Why the extra /login again?

OK, so I can get all the way through to signing in with Google:
Try:

```
root_url = https://grafana.redacted.io/
serve_from_sub_path = false
```

Google Console left as: https://grafana.redacted.io/login/google
Visit link 2 above, page loads, sign in screen appears, 2FA on google all good, then

"Safari can't open the page "https://grafana.redacted.io/login/google?state...etc.etc.""

Why, when all redirects are set equal is a /login being appended to the URL?
Spent ages on this, and would really appreciate some help
Thanks

Comment: What ever the uri that the redirect_uri_mismatch error message tells you is missing just add it to google developer console.   The question is though is it the redirect uri thats wrong or the javascript origin?  Try watching this https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ

Comment: OK, so, I didn't give up after making this post and I have it working. I'm not posting this as the solution in case I'm point blank missing something/identified a bug: Grafana.ini: `root_url = https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/google/` & `serve_from_sub_path = true` and Google redirect url: `https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/google/login/google`     - it works a treat! Notice the pointless /google/ why this makes any difference I don't know. Site is accessed via  `https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/`

Answer (score 1):

In grafana.ini (v8.0.5) whenever I set the `root_url` to that directed by the Grafana Google OAuth2 docs it added stuff to the url and this through a redirect mismatch error.

Thanks @DalmTo for the video link. I took this and experimented...follow below

Grafana.ini
`root_url = https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/xxxx/` &
`serve_from_sub_path = true`

The "xxxx" can be anything except the word "login". I've tried some random stuff and it all works, except using the word login; I'm actually using "google" lol. Ensure to append the final `/`

Google Console: set the Redirect URI to `https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/xxxx/login/google`

Grafana UI will be available at `https://grafana.redacted.io:3000/`

It's not really a solution, more a work around.